# IndexedDB: Retrieve item with max value

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Suppose I have an `IndexedDB` collection with name `items`. All items have fields:

- id
- name
- revision

`revision` field is a number field. I need to retrieve an item with max value of revision (or at least just retrive max revision value). What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First thing you need to do is create index on the `revision` field.

Then you need a search function which will use that index and open the index with inverse order of the objects. Then the first object will be the object you are looking for.

```
var index = objectStore.index('revision');
index.openCursor(null, 'prev');
```

The null states that you are searching for all values not a specific one, and the second parameter is the direction of the search.

Here is the sample code:

```
function getMaxNumber (callback) {
    var openReq = indexedDB.open(baseName);
    openReq.onsuccess = function() {
        var db = openReq.result;
        var transaction = db.transaction(objectStoreName, 'readonly');
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(objectStoreName);
        var index = objectStore.index('revision');
        var openCursorRequest = index.openCursor(null, 'prev');
        var maxRevisionObject = null;

        openCursorRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
            if (event.target.result) {
                maxRevisionObject = event.target.result.value; //the object with max revision
            }
        };
        transaction.oncomplete = function (event) {
            db.close();
            if(callback) //you'll need a calback function to return to your code
                callback(maxRevisionObject);
        };
    }
}
```

Since the `IndexedDB` api is async you would need a callback function to return the value to your code.

Comment: One more question: why not just call callback in openCursorRequest.onsuccess listener? Is it important to call it after db.close() ?

Comment: No Alex, this is just the way I use the API, since most of the time I iterate through multiple values with the 'onsuccess' event and return the values in the 'oncomplete' event. In your case it would be faster to return the value within the 'onsuccess' event.

Comment: I never close the db, there is a dbPromise in the module I wrote that when resolved returns the db but it is only set once when the module is loaded. So after getting the value I do: `cursor && cursor.advance(1000000);` this casses onsuccess function to be called once more but e.target.result is null.